# Support for multiple ways to sign into Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

So we are building an application which has to support two ways of creating a new account.

1. user creates an account with a email and password combination
2. user adds an `Authorization` header with a JWT token from a trusted third party. This JWT is verified and contains the necessary information such as email to create a user in our system.

Creating a user this way works fine. However, I am not sure how to deal with the subsequent authentication. The current system uses session-based authentication.

**Question**: A user that created an account with the JWT should also be able to login without a password. I can think of two way to achieve this:

1. Validate the JWT and manually start a session. But how can I start a session manually without a password?
2. Add a filter to the Spring Security Chain that checks whether a JWT is present. If so it adds the user the the security context. If no JWT is present it requires the user provide a valid email, password combination. Any resources on how two do this conditional chaining?

Any hint for an advantage or disadvantage for the two methods is appreciated.

Comment: On your first option, I was thinking: how about seamlessly creating a username and password for the user when you validate the token? It may not be the best solution, but its a work around worth a try

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this work around would definitely work, but other fixes would need to be applied such that these users are not able to reset their password...